# jquery global variables don't work

Tags: jquery, global

I am having problems with the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var $selection = $('<div class="image-selection" />')
            .css({
                opacity : 0.5,
                position : 'absolute'

            })

var $content = $('.content');

$('img', $content).click(function(){selectItem($(this))});

function selectItem(itemSelected){      

    $image = itemSelected;

    $image.wrap($selection);

    $selection.width(150).height(150);

}
```

});

I declared $selection as the global variable, but for some reason when it is inside of a function the width or height don't change(The size of the selection changes):
if i do the following, it works:

```
var $selection = $('<div class="image-selection" />')
            .css({
                opacity : 0.5,
                position : 'absolute'

            })

var $content = $('.content');
$selection.width(150).height(150);
```

I will appreciate very much if some one understands what is happening, and can tell me , i have been trying to figure it out this, but i am really struggling.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrap $image with $selection, the div is now a new object (a copy of $selection) in the DOM rather than the actual disconnected element in memory.  Try changing to this:

```
$image.wrap($selection);
$image.parent('div.image-selection').width(150).height(150);
```

Comment: agree.. or just chain parent() after the wrap

Comment: Yes, chaining would be good.  I just wanted to leave an original line in there unchanged, as a point of reference to the position in the original code.

Comment: i tried that before and it works, i just cant understand why i cant use $selection, because of the wrap ?...

Comment: oww ...  well it seems that if i put the statement $selection.width(150).height(150); before the wrap it works... can you explain what is the wrap doing? i am a little bit confused thanks very much!

Comment: @ThePrincessKarina because at that point, you're changing the values of a different object.  The object wrapping $image is no longer $selection - it is a copy of $selection.

Comment: oooooooooooowww!!!, thanks so much... I was thinking I can use $selection everywhere...

Answer (score 1):

You're not declaring it as global - you're declaring it within the scope of the function executed when `document.ready`.  Ideally, put `var $selection` before `document.ready` and remove the `var` when you refer to it inside that function.  That will make it global.

Comment: It's true it isn't global, but all of the places that use it are also within the document.ready handler so it is in scope.

Comment: so when you say that is in scope, doyou mean that it will still work, or do i need to put this variable outside the document.ready ?

Comment: I mean that the variable declaration for `$selection` does not need to be moved outside document.ready because it will "work" in the sense of being accessible where it is. The problem you are having is not related to this (Jake has explained the _real_ problem).

Comment: @nnnnnn of course, thanks - I misread the question as 2 separate bits of code.